# Cannot call method onCreateOptionsMenu () on startup for napp drawer

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, drawer, appcelerator-titanium, oncreateoptionsmenu

I have a problem only with nap drawer module.I have this code:

```
**drawer = NapDrawerModule.createDrawer({
//parameter for the drawer
});**
```

Then I have:
*

```
*drawer.getActivity().onCreateOptionsMenu = function(e) {
//code for creation menu**
}
```

Problem is that when I started application the method onCreateOptionsMenu() not called so my menu item not show up.When I pressed physical menu button it show up.
I noticed that this is problem only with NapDrawer.I tried make simple TI.UI.createWindow(),add method onCreateOptionsMenu() and it work.
I don't know what is a problem with  drawer.I use titanium 5.0 and target android SDK 22.

Comment: I found the solution for the problem above.Anyone who has this kind of problem the next solution work for me.You need to add in your nap drawer create method next attribute:hamburgerIcon:true

Comment: Nikolai, could you add that as an answer and accept is so that the question will be marked as answered?

Comment: I answered on my question now.Ok now?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for the problem above.Anyone who has this kind of problem the next solution work for me.You need to add in your nap drawer create method next attribute:hamburgerIcon:true